# Switch in WordPress-function that doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress-theme that has to be used on multiple sites. So I wrote this function, to determine which site the theme is on:

```
/*
 * Check which site
*/
function determine_site() {

  $the_site = '';
  $URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

  switch( $URL ){
    case 'domain1.com':
    case 'develop1.ment.com':
      $the_site = 'domain1_com';
      break;
    case 'domain2.com':
    case 'develop2.ment.com':
      $the_site = 'domain2_com';
      break;
    default;
      $the_site = 'domain_undetermined';
      break;
  }
  return $the_site;
}
```

And this function is then called from another function, which adds it to the body-class on the site, as such:

```
/*
 * Add body class
 */
function add_custom_body_class( $classes ) {
  $which_language = determine_site();
  $classes[] = $which_language;
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_custom_body_class' );
```

But it reaches the default-case and sets `domain_undetermined` as the `body`-class (which it should match on one of the first cases). If I print out the `$URL`-var in the top of the `determine_site`-function, as such:

```
function determine_site() {

  $the_site = '';
  $URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  echo '<pre>;
  print_r($URL);
  echo '</pre>;
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Then it outputs this (!?):

```
develop1.ment.comclass="home page-template-default page page-id-11 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support wp-custom-logo domain_undetermined">
```

Why does it print the end of the `body`-classes, as well?

Another thing that might help figure out where the hatchet is burried... If I run `sanitize_title` (a WordPress-function) on `$URL`, as such:

```
function determine_site() {

  $the_site = '';
  $URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $URL = sanitize_title( $URL );
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($URL);
  echo '</pre>';
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

... Then it returns this (even though I am on the `develop1.ment.com`-domain:

```
www-domain1-comclass="home page-template-default page page-id-11 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support wp-custom-logo domain_undetermined">
```

The development-server does some proxy-stuff, which explains this last bit, - but it doesn't explain all of these mysteries.

Comment: Can you also output the $URL variable to make sure your comparison in switch are at least getting true. If you are getting default it means comparisons are all false and so it goes to default. Lets see the output of $URL first.

Comment: 'develop1.ment.com' != 'develop.ment1.com'

Comment: Thanks @B68C.. I've now corrected that typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work in place of your own "add body class" function?

```
/**
 * Add domain to body class for each site.
 */
function my_multisite_body_classes( $classes ) {
  $current_blog = get_blog_details( get_current_blog_id() );
  $classes[] = $current_blog->domain;
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'my_multisite_body_classes');
```